# GxtRtl Html and HtmlContainer flips input html content

Tags: html, right-to-left, gxt

I use Gxt-2.2.5-Rtl *(http://code.google.com/p/gxt-rtl/)* and try to show html content through `HtmlContainer`'s `setUrl()` method. But unfortunately the result is flipped version of my expected output. For example suppose our input html contains a table which starts columns from right to left as id, name, description. So what we get is a table that their column starts from expected order BUT FROM LEFT TO RIGHT!

I used Gxt's `Html` and Gwt's `HTML` and `HtmlPanel` classes, but this problem doesn't solve.

In addition I should say when I use `TabItem` or `ContentPanel`'s `setUrl()` method this problem disappears. But I prefer to don't use that method and because: 
1- Just last loaded iFrame is visible at a time. This means that navigating through other preloaded tab items displays a blank page.
2- Poor control over loaded page through GWT, like catching click events and etc.

Expected output:
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/yow6l

Wrong output:
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/8opdt

I changed the titles to English for better communicating! :)

Thanks!